# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Здраствуйте, не могу сделать SQL-запрос. Мне нужно выбрать столбец film_name из базы данных.[image: введите сюда описание изображения] Но произошла ошибка [image: введите сюда описание изображения] - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:23 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 23

index.php

```
<?php
      require_once 'includes/config.php';
    ?>

   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
     <title><?php echo $config['title']; ?></title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/media.css">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Revalia" rel="stylesheet">
   </head>
   <body>

   <?php require_once "includes/header.php"; ?>

   <section>
     <div class="container">
       <?php
             $stmt = $pdo->query('SELECT film_name FROM new_film');
             while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
               echo $row['film_name'];
             };
        ?>
     </div>
   </section>

   <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

connection.php

```
<?php

      $host = 'localhost';
      $username = 'root';
      $password = '';
      $dbname = 'main';

      try {
        $dsn = "mysql:host = $host; dbname = $dbname";

        $opt = [
          PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
          PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
          PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
        ];

        $pdo = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $opt);
      }
      catch (PDOException $e) {
        die('Not connect: ' . $e->getMessage());
      }

      $pdo = null;
    ?>
```

Comment: Во-первых, в первом куске кода я не вижу подключение `connection.php`, т.е. что-то типа: `require_once 'includes/connection.php';`, если он все-же подключается, то главная проблема в том, что вам нужно удалить строчку `$pdo = null;` и все будет работать

Comment: Подключил файл и забрал $pdo = null; Выдало новую ошибку - Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php:25 Stack trace: #0 C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php(25): PDO->query('SELECT film_nam...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\index.php on line 25

Comment: [Как правильно соединяться с PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo_examples/connect_to_mysql)